# Read a file in a Bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a file in my file system. I want to read that file in bash script. File format is different i want to read only selected values from the file. I don't want to read the whole file as the file is very huge. Below is my file format:

```
Name=TEST
Add=TEST
LOC=TEST
```

In the file it will have data like above. From that I want to get only Add date in a variable. Could you please suggest me how I can do this.

As of now i am doing this to read the file:

```
file="data.txt"
while IFS= read line
do
    # display $line or do somthing with $line
    echo "$line"
done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the right tool meant for the job, `Awk` in this case to speed things up!

```
dateValue="$(awk -F"=" '$1=="Add"{print $2; exit}' file)"
printf "%s\n" "dateValue"
TEST
```

The idea is to split input lines by `=` as the de-limiter. The `awk` logic works by checking the `$1` field which equals to `Add` and prints the corresponding value associated with it.

The `exit` part after print is optional. It will quit the processing as soon as the `Add` string is met. It will help in quick processing if the file is huge as you have indicated.

Comment: Is `exit` really optional?

Comment: @codeforester: `optional` as in, the command will still work as long as there are no similar `$1` values in `Add`. But in a case if it is not present, the command will take too much time to run on a big file, but nevertheless will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite your loop this way, notice the `break` after you got your line:

```
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  if [[ $value == "Add" ]]; then
    # your logic
    break
  fi
done < "$file"
```

If your intention is to just get the very first occurrence of "Add=", then you could use `grep` this way:

```
value=$(grep -m 1 '^Add=' "$file" | cut -f2 -d=)
```

Comment: Appreciate your answering in `bash`, but it is not really a tool for processing when considering performance, read through http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for a detailed/well-explained research on this